# Tricky javascript code for fun (and learning)

Tags: javascript

there's a short JavaScript code which is a bit hard to read, I admit. And also, there's a task with it. Here's the code:

```
x_ = _ = _y = love = null, _x = "x", _y = "y";
console.log(Infinity in window & !!0 == !!!1 & +~~_ + "" === _ ? _ + _x : _ + _y);
```

where output is `nully`. Output should be "value x" (where value is the value of `love`).

Ps.: You can only change the value of `love` at declaration, nothing else. Once again: you can give `love` any value, but output must contain "x" at the end, right after `love`'s value.

**EDIT:**
There was a mistyping problem at declaration, fixed.

Comment: This isn't a puzzle site.....

Comment: its not, and I'm not trying to make a puzzle.. I've been asked this question and I'm really curious about the answer.. I'm looking for a solution, that's it

Comment: it's not really clear at all what the question is, though.

Comment: x_=_=_y="love"=null gives "Invalid left-hand side in assignment", which I would have expect since you can't assign anything to a string constant like "love"

Comment: here's the declaration: `x_=_=_y=love=null,_x="x",_y="y";` where you can only change the variable `love` value to get output which is for example `truex` so there's an "x" at the end.

Comment: First put a lot of parentheses in the expression, then repeatably do reductions (e.g. `!0 → true`), then replace `?:` with `if else`, then ask again if anything is unclear.

Comment: finally I solved it... set any number sorrounded by `"` as the value of `love` for example `... love="2"` and the output will be "2x". Thanks @Joel and @Kay for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following:

```
Infinity in window & !!0 == !!!1 & +~~_ + "" === _ ? _ + _x : _ + _y
```

You can put parenthesis as such:

```
(Infinity in window & !!0 == !!!1 & +~~_ + "") === (_) (? _ + _x) : (_ + _y)
```

"Infinity in window" is true, !!0 is false, !!!1 is false, ~~_ is 0 (this, I don't know why). So The left operand gives:

```
true & false == false & +0 + ""
```

This gives 0. Which is not strictly equal to null (_) , so the :? operator returns  _+_y. The operation (null + "y") returns a string where null is converted to "null", so you get "nully".

Comment: ~~_ is 0 because ~ is a bitwise NOT (inverts 0s and 1s in the binary representation of a number). Bitwise operations only work on integers, so ~~ is a shorter way to convert to integer by inverting twice. It corresponds to Math.floor, but might be slower on some implementations (tested in chrome) so such a hack isn't recommended.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it's constructive and clear and helped me to solve the "puzzle"